# How much reputation is required to edit a question or answer?

Tags: support, reputation

According to the [privilege page](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit), a reputation of 1000 is required. But I already edited questions and answers.

Does a reputation of 1000 allow to edit a Q/A without the peer review and avoid to have the following message?

> **Thanks for your edit!**
>   This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you reach 1000 reputation you can edit any question or answer without having a peer review it. This means that your edit takes effect immediately.

Once we leave beta though the requirements will increase to 2500 reputation; as will every other privilege.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a minimum reputation to edit **with** having a peer review? Can a new user (rep. 1) edit any question or answer?

Comment: @Morgan Anybody can suggest edits, even unregistered users. Though for unregistered users it's called _improve this question_.